# Passing values to other components using props in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm binding some text values when a certain div is clicked in my react application. Now i'm facing a problem on passing these text values to another component using props.

My code looks like this

```
class PostOptionBar extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {

            postType: 'text',

        }

    }

    textType(postType) {

        this.setState({postType});

    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div className="post_type_selection_div">

                <div className="post_type_btn">

                    <div className="horiz_center" onClick={this.textType.bind(this,'text')}>
                        <img src={StarIcon} className="post_type_icon"/>
                        <a className="post_type_text">Text</a>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div className="post_type_btn" onClick={this.textType.bind(this,'imageVote')}>

                    <div className="horiz_center">
                        <img src={StarIcon} className="post_type_icon"/>
                        <a className="post_type_text">Image poll</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div className="post_type_btn" onClick={this.textType.bind(this,'poll')}>

                    <div className="horiz_center">
                        <img src={StarIcon} className="post_type_icon"/>
                        <a className="post_type_text">Text poll</a>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default PostOptionBar;
```

I can bind the values successfully within this class. If i log the `postType` i can clearly see that. But i want to pass `postType` to another component. I'm loading `PostOptionBar` in my other component like this.

```
 <div className="polaroid">
   <PostOptionBar/>
 <div>
```

I'm trying to do something like this in my 2nd component.But because i cannot pass `postType` from my 1st component to 2nd one i cannot do this.

```
    renderTab() {

        switch (this.state.postType) {
            case 'text':
                return <TextPost/>
            case 'imageVote':
                return <ImageVote/>
            case 'poll':
                return <TextVotePost/>

        }
    }
```

Comment: not clear, where you want to define this method `renderTab`? and to which component you want to pass postType ?

Comment: renderTab is my 2nd component. But i'm setting my postType in 1st component. To renderTab to work i need postType value in 2nd component.

Comment: I agree with @MayankShukla your question isn't clear. But passing the props is very easy if you meant this ´<PostOptionBar postType={this.state.postType}/> and the props postType will be accessible in PostOptionBar component as a simple props

Comment: @CraZyDroiD you are rendering `<PostOptionBar/>` at one place olny or at multiple places ?

Comment: only at one place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve that issue, you need to manage the `state` by the parent component of `PostOptionBar` then pass the value to `PostOptionBar` and other components also. Also pass a function to `PostOptionBar` component to update the state of parent component.

Parent Component of `PostOptionBar`:

```
<div className="polaroid">
    <PostOptionBar postType = {this.state.postType} changeType = {this.changeType}/>
<div>

changeType = (postType) => {
   this.setState({postType})
}
```

Inside `PostOptionBar` use the props value `this.props.postType`:

```
class PostOptionBar extends Component {

    textType(postType) {
        this.props.changeType(postType);  // call the parent component to update the state
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

set state using

```
<Component2 postType={this.state.postType}/>
```

and fetch in component2 using

```
this.props.postType
```

Comment: All i want to know is how can i pass the value binded when onClick={this.textType.bind(this,'text')} to my next component.

Comment: your value text is binded to posttype so this.state.posttype means your text is set as state and when you will fetch it with this.props.posttype then it will give you value of posttype ie text.Give it a try